# Is the latest Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye trustable?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I,m thinking of upgrading my Pi-Os and I do not know for sure if Bulleseye is fully trustable and might have a glitch on me. Does it have aney problems, can I trust it, or is it dangerous or hard to install?

Thank's for your time.

Comment: I just want to know if it's safe. :)

Comment: perfectly safe, runs perfectly well on 5 of my pi's  (2xpi4, 1xpi3b, 1xpi3a+, 1xcm4)

Comment: See [Bullseye - Comments and bug reports thread](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1934787#p1934787) and form your own opinion.

Comment: `install it without risking my data` - whenever you install raspberry pi OS, you install a base system - are you asking about **upgrading** to bullseye? That has an 80% success rate (for me, 4 out of 5 upgraded without an issue) ... to not risk your data, you would make a backup image of your current install, then upgrade (following instructions found on Raspberry PI's own forum) - so, if you plan ahead, there's absolutely zero risk to your data

Comment: by the way, the link to the upgrade instructions is https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=323279 - I succeeded on 2xPi4, pi3B and CM4 - only failure was on a pi3A+ - however, I *may* have forgotten to `apt get update && apt get upgrade` in buster before starting the upgrade to bullseye

Comment: I'al do that. I do not yet have a backup sd-card but I will get one befor I upgrade.

Comment: I just upgraded and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it is never a good idea to deploy a newly released OS into a production environment without thorough testing first. Fortunately, the Raspberry Pi itself is primarily a test environment anyway.

One thing you could try is to simply power down your Pi, remove the SD card, mount another, newly flashed SD card with Bullseye on it, then mount your old SD card in a card reader via the Pi's USB port. This way you can boot the Pi from Bullseye, and still have access to your data. If you encounter any issues with the rollout, simply swap the SD cards back over, and resume booting from your former OS installation.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to see if anybody had any problems with it.

Comment: While other people's experiences may be somewhat helpful, what really matters is how it will work in your own environment, for your purposes. Someone else here mentioned "a couple glitches with the audio", but if you don't need audio, that won't bother you. I think the common acronym explaining this is "YMMV". 

Comment: So, how would I get rid of that problem if I got it?

Comment: Well, I'm only new to SE as well, but I gather that the idea is to ask about problems that you currently have, and not "what if" situations. It seems that @random_ubuntu_user found a solution to that particular problem, and might post such a solution for you. All I'm saying is, not all known bugs and issues affect everyone the same, depending on what is important to you.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using it for a while. I have had a couple glitches with the audio, but I worked them out.  It is very trustable, fast, and stable.  A 5-star rating by me.